# How to ask for confirmation with input values before submitting a form in PHP using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to ask for a JavaScript confirmation with input values before submitting a form, when a user clicks the submit button in HTML.

```js
function ask() {
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to send ' + amount + ' to ' + phone + '?');
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="9999999999" />
  <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="1000" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="ask()" value="Send" />
</form>
```

When a user clicks the submit button, it should show a javascript confirmation dialog asking "Are you sure you want to send 1000 to 9999999999?" and then when the user will click the "OK" button on the confirmation dialog box, the form should be submitted.

But now it submits the form directly without asking for confirmation, when user clicks the submit button.

Please help!

Comment: You're missing a `.` in `documentgetElementById`. You also don't ever return anything from your function.

Comment: @j08691 
I've corrected it. But still, on clicking the submit button it submits the form directly without asking for confirmation

Comment: Just add on submit event listener to the form, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `ask()` doesnt return the confirmation boolean, so:

```js
function ask() {
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to send ' + amount + ' to ' + phone + '?');
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="9999999999" />
  <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="1000" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="return ask()" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: I've corrected it. But still, on clicking the submit button it submits the form directly without asking for confirmation.

Comment: @AmlanDutta that's because you removed the `return` from your onclick statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do this,

```js
document.getElementById("submitForm").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  if(confirm('Are you sure you want to send ' + amount + ' to ' + phone + '?'))
  {  
   document.getElementById("submitForm").onsubmit = null;
     document.getElementById("submitForm").submit();
 }
}
```

```html
<form id="submitForm" method="post" action="submit.php">
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="9999999999" />
  <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="1000" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: I've corrected it. But still, on clicking the submit button it submits the form directly without asking for confirmation

Comment: But it doesnt, even here on running the snippet it works perfectly, did you corrected the . in documentgetElementById

Comment: But in my case, only the marked answer worked! Anyways Thank you so much. You tried to help me too :-)